# Connecting with wrong collation to a mysql server?

Tags: mysql, go

I have a Golang program that may connect to databases with different character sets or collation.

For example the default at the time of writing of the Golang MYSQL driver is **utf8mb4_general_ci** https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#collation

However if I connect to a database configured like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE example character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Can I expect "bad things to happen"? Indexes not to work?

Answer (score 0):

In most case, there are no problem.  For example, column collation is used regardless connection collation when `WHERE column=?` is used.

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html

But I can't speak it's 100% safe.  It's safe to use one collation all place.

Comment: I noticed there was problem when Execing SQL https://github.com/unee-t/bz-database/issues/128#issuecomment-490724862 I am tracking master of the Go SQL driver btw 8056f2ca4aa7be2e2e10ab01426a630d5a5bfa81

Comment: I don't know which query caused such an error.  Could you give us some short example?